# Admin Media grid view images won't load

Tags: php, images, ajax, wp-admin, media-library

All I did was adding this in my functions.php file:

```
function save_nb_image()
{
    global $wpdb;

            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $file = wp_get_attachment_url($id);

                if ( !is_wp_error($id) )
                {
                    $meta = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($id, $file);
                    $meta = nb_image_crop($meta);
                    wp_update_attachment_metadata($id, $meta);
                }

    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nb-image-autofix', 'save_nb_image' );
```

Then I tried to call it from a custom button in image edit form. Something didn't worked because nothing happened.

Then little later when I went into the Media Library again, the images wouldn't load. Chrome Console log said something about problem with mixed content. I have pretty recently changed to SSL/https so I thought that might been the problem. Although it's strange that change for some weeks ago make this affect now. I have been in media library a lot of times after that change and everything has worked perfectly.

But anyway, IF there is a SSL problem, I added "SSL Insecure Content Fixer" plugin to let that clear out everything. And I ran that plugin and then went in to the media library again. The console errors was now gone. But the images is still not loading. There is just a load spinner going on forever.

I have also tried activate the debug mode from wp_config but there is no related errors.

I have also tried re-installing the Wordpress version from Dashboard > Updates.

I have also of course tried remove the code I mentioned above.

What is there else to try?

**Edit:** I think it might be a database issue. Cause I even tried to remove all the files except /wp-content folder and wp-config.php file. And installed the older WP 4.4 version. Then went in and updated to latest version. After that: Still no images in grid view....

**Edit, 27 feb 2017:** I have found out that `wp_get_attachment_url()` was the wrong function to use since I wanted the absolute path and not the URL. So the right function to use is `get_attached_file()`. When I used the `wp_get_attachment_url()` function the ajax was loading very long time and returned a lot of strange code that I suspect was the image on some kind of code format. After changing to `get_attached_file()` the loading was much faster and the functionality of everything I wanted with the code did work as expected. However, maybe something with the earlier code made a mess in the database causing the Grid Mode problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is now solved. Thanks to user "blobfolio" [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39974#comment:2):

> It sounds like you may have corrupted the image metadata. Have you
>   tried running a plugin like
>   https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/ to
>   regenerate the images/meta?

**Solution:**

So the solution is to force regenerate all the thumbnails. For example using the plugin mentioned above in the quote.

Comment: That does not fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently. I had moved over a theme with some plugin specific code in the functions.php. I forgot however to install said plugin. The grid view in the media gallery wouldn't load, but the list view would.

**What Fixed It For Me**

- Remove plugin specific code from Functions file.
- Install proper plugin
- Add plugin specific code to Functions file.

I'm not sure if that will work for you but maybe check your plugins.

Comment: I tried to just remove ALL the code from functions.php. Didn't helped. And I can also mention that there is no response at all from ajax-post.php in Network -> ajax-post.php -> Response.

Comment: Sorry I meant admin-ajax.php

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue recently, after inspecting admin page the `admin-ajax.php` response contain non-json response. It is because my client adding extra code in `functions.php` that somehow append inline `<style></style>` to the `admin-ajax.php` response.

**Solution:** Check the `admin-ajax.php` response, if there are non-json return or invalid json return you should investigate where the extra ajax response come from.